# Understanding how ParallaxView works

Tags: uwp

I am trying to wrap my head around ParallaxView with the following example:

```
    <Grid Background="Yellow"
          Width="500"
          Height="300">
        <ParallaxView VerticalShift="0"
                      HorizontalShift="500"
                      Source="{x:Bind scrollView}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Height="300">
                <Border Width="500" 
                        Background="Red"/>
                <Border Width="500" 
                        Background="Blue"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ParallaxView>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollView"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Border Background="Transparent"
                    Width="1000"
                    Height="300" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

So the parallax view has a horizontal StackPanel with two Border's each 500px wide.

The ScrollViewer which acts as ParallaxView source, has a transparent Border with the same width as the StackPanel (1000px).

Note I set HorizontalShift of 500, so I am expecting the ParallaxView to scroll horizontally the StackPanel by 500 px. I am expecting to see the 2nd Border beginning from the left margin.

When running the app, without any scrolling, I can see the a bit of the 2nd Border already, it looks like somehow the ParallaxView scrolls already a bit the StackPanel:

[image]

Why does this happen? Why does the ParallaxView scrolls the StackPanel horizontally at start?

Comment: I could reproduce this behavior, For verifying this you could refer this [blog](https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2018/03/14/everything-about-the-uwp-parallaxview-control/). And it looks by design. When you set  `HorizontalShift` property, and the `Border` will scale by a certain ratio. It same as `VerticalShift`.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Thanks for reply. I don't think that's the reason. If you scroll to the right, you can see there's a gap, and that gap seem to be exactly of width of vertical scroll bar, albeit there's no vertical scroll bar. There seems to be some sort of bug.

Comment: I'd appreciate some thoughtful advice on this from someone at Microsoft, thanks!